# How to save uitable() to PDF, JPG, etc

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-uitable

How can I save my `uitable()` to a PDF, JPG, etc.?

Using Matlab R2018a, no fancy add-ons. Looking for solutions using tables, not arrays, due to size/complexity of the real data.

```
    % construct simple table as example %
    t = array2table(zeros(4,1));
    t.Properties.VariableNames{'Var1'} = 'id';
    t.id(:) = 1;
    t.fieldA = {'a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'};
    t.GroupCount = [22; 1; 19; 0];

    f = uifigure;
    uit = uitable(f, 'Data', t);
    % what command to save to PDF? or JPG, PNG, whatever
```

Note that `f = figure` doesn't work, otherwise it would be easy to save as PDF (I think it is having trouble passing the table `t`, I'm not sure):

```
f = figure; 
uit = uitable(f, 'Data', t);

Error using uitable
Functionality not supported with figures created with the figure function. For more information, see Graphics Support in App Designer.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create it as a [**`figure`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html) instead of a [**`uifigure`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uifigure.html) to save it. But you cannot pass a table to it. You need a simple array or a cell-array for that. Since you have mixed data type, therefore cell-array is the way to go. Use [**`table2cell`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table2cell.html) to convert your table to a cell-array.

```
f = figure;
uit = uitable(f, 'Data', table2cell(t));
uit.ColumnName={t.Properties.VariableNames{:}}; %renaming columns to that of table
uit.RowName=[]; %removing default row numbering as in your uitable
```

Now you are good to go with [saving](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html) your figure in any of your desired formats. e.g:

```
saveas(f, 'q60974307.png');
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: that is perfect, worked like a charm and you gave a great explanation; thank you